# Cannot access the flask app after deploying to Heroku using docker with conda environment

Tags: python, docker, heroku, flask, conda

I've been trying to deploy my flask app to Heroku. Since I need to install some packages like `osmnx` via `conda-forge` and require `python3`, I created a new conda environment in my `Dockerfile` using `heroku/miniconda` image. The image worked fine on my machine:

```
docker build -t myapp:latest .
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 myapp:latest
```

I can access the app via `http://localhost:5000`.

But after I pushed it to heroku and tried to access the app, I got `application error`. Where did I go wrong?  Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
heroku create
heroku container:push web 
heroku container:release web
```

app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)  # flask

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print('hi')
    return jsonify({'predict': 'hi'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM heroku/miniconda

# Grab requirements.txt.
ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt

# Add our code
ADD ./webapp /opt/webapp/
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

RUN conda update --all

RUN conda create -n myapp python=3.8

RUN echo "source activate myapp && \ 
  conda install -y gunicorn flask && \
  gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi" > ~/.bashrc
```

requirements.txt

```
Jinja2
Werkzeug
distribute
wsgiref
```

Error logs

```
2019-12-12T08:05:36.198329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\52227\ wsgi`
2019-12-12T08:05:38.192281+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:05:38 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2019-12-12T08:05:38.192904+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:05:38 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:52227 (3)
2019-12-12T08:05:38.193027+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:05:38 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-12-12T08:05:38.196937+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:05:38 +0000] [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
2019-12-12T08:05:39.875668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-12-12T08:05:57.045392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-spire-78220.herokuapp.com request_id=821c59f7-1d43-445f-ab32-189213d39e49 fwd="71.234.178.193" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=172 protocol=http
2019-12-12T08:05:57.564757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-spire-78220.herokuapp.com request_id=98f73ce0-0746-4829-9d5c-21f0c14eaf74 fwd="71.234.178.193" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=385 protocol=http
2019-12-12T08:39:51.048036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-12-12T08:39:51.059265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-12-12T08:39:52.029208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-12-12T08:39:52.045411+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:39:52 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-12-12T08:39:52.046245+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:39:52 +0000] [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
2019-12-12T08:39:52.146325+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 08:39:52 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-12-12T08:39:52.248536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-12T15:53:31.107555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2019-12-12T15:53:31.111206+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-12-12T15:53:33.445428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\49441\ wsgi`
2019-12-12T15:53:35.796555+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 15:53:35 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2019-12-12T15:53:35.797246+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 15:53:35 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:49441 (3)
2019-12-12T15:53:35.797379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 15:53:35 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-12-12T15:53:35.802113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 15:53:35 +0000] [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
2019-12-12T15:53:37.249954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-12-12T15:53:39.168666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-spire-78220.herokuapp.com request_id=15228cf6-1e89-4a61-8588-e27bd81ec009 fwd="71.234.178.193" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=172 protocol=http
2019-12-12T16:08:02.009401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-12-12T16:08:02.016006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-12-12T16:08:01.808927+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user user@email
2019-12-12T16:08:01.808927+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (18473777b9fd) by user user@email
2019-12-12T16:08:03.215311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-12-12T16:08:03.233100+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 16:08:03 +0000] [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
2019-12-12T16:08:03.242295+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 16:08:03 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-12-12T16:08:03.346104+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-12 16:08:03 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-12-12T16:08:03.457209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-12T16:08:26.328041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/bash`
2019-12-12T16:08:28.907322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-12T16:08:28.910586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-12T16:08:28.888393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-12T16:08:45.746338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/bash`
2019-12-12T16:08:48.097260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-12T16:08:48.078172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-12T16:08:48.851256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-spire-78220.herokuapp.com request_id=79097307-40bb-4100-b99f-1f701c1ee1fb fwd="71.234.178.193" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Comment: add  `CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000","wsgi"]`, RUN command only run at build time

Comment: @Adiii It returned `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"gunicorn\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.` on my machine.